# Play 2.6.22 with ebean 4.1.0 can't compile

Tags: playframework

After migration play from 2.5 to 2.6.22 I got an error about

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/Configuration
        at play.db.ebean.ModelsConfigLoader.apply(ModelsConfigLoader.java:27)
```

following is my plugin.sbt file

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.22")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.0.1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [GitHub Repo for `play-ebean`](https://github.com/playframework/play-ebean#releases), I think you need at least version `4.0.2` for Play Framework Version `2.6.x`